# How much gigabytes of space will windows 7 32 bit version take after installation on the hard disk?

Tags: windows-7

I want to know how much space (in gigabytes) will a clean installation of windows 7 32 bit version take after installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Windows 7 Professional 32-bit with all Windows Updates up to today (Includes .NET Framework) it took up about 31 GB hard disk space.

However, I have 8GB RAM.  After running Disk Cleanup, deleting other installation files, and disabling Hibernation and the Page File, I freed up another 12 GB.

You're looking at about 20GB after some tweaking.

Answer (score -1):

They say approximately 15GB - 20GB will acquire. [Official](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements) document is here.

Comment: The answer is 15-20GB. Link was for reference.